# "-jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" en un .sh no me funciona

Tags: java, screen

mi problema es que no me carga la instrucción "-jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" en un script prender mi servidor.

Tengo 3 servidores prendidos y no me funciona si quiero colocar nuevos servidores a funcionar.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    while true
    do
    echo "Iniciando el servidor..."
    java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 spigot.jar -o false nogui
    echo -e 'Para parar el servidor completamente presiona ctrl-C nuevamente!'
    echo "Reinciando en:"
    for i in 3 2 1
    do
    echo "$i..."
    sleep 1
    done
    echo "Prendido!"
    done
```

tengo la misma script en los otros 3 servidores que si funciona, intente muchas maneras de poder saber que pasaba, no sé si sea mi java o algún problema con la codificación de los archivos .yml que no creo porque ya trate de poner todos en utf-8 y no funciona.

Aquí mi java instalado.

```
    openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_312-8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04-b07)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.312-b07, mixed mode)
```

Aquí mis locales de la maquina.

```
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    LANGUAGE=
    LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=
```

Espero que me pueda alguien ayudar, ya he estado leyendo muchos problemas similares pero ninguno me funciono. No sé que otra cosa pueda estar interviniendo al momento de prender la screen.

Comment: ¿Obtienes algún error?

Comment: no, simplemente no carga el símbolo "&" y aparece este en su lugar "§"